# Why a parameter is missing even I am passing the value and correct param?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have this code that sends a param to a stored procedure in SQL but it doesn't work i.e. it says that parameter is not provided but when I assign default value in procedure to the parameter then it doesn't throw error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'GetEquipmentChildDataByFunLoc' expects parameter '@FunctionalLocation_IN' which was not supplied.

Func:

```
public DataSet VaLues(string MT_F)
{
    string query = "GetEquipment";
    string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SAPConnection"].ConnectionString;

    DataSet dsEquipmentData = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FunctionalLocation_IN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = MT_FunctionalLocation;

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, ConnectionString);

        cn.Open();

        sqlDA.Fill(dsEquipmentData);

        cn.Close();
    }

    return dsEquipmentData;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEquipment] 
    @FunctionalLocation_IN VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM eq
    WHERE eq.FunctionalLocation= @FunctionalLocation_IN
END
```

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `MT_FunctionalLocation`?

Comment: You create the cmd, but don't use to fill the dataset.

Comment: Nothing in this code even _executes_ `cmd`...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to initialize adapter with the command:

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```